# How can I create a separate data system for my program?

Tags: c#, sandbox

Is it possible to create a separate file system for your program to boot from? Let me expand on my issue:

I wish to set my program up to check for updates at runtime. If any are found, it will download them, install them into the current data system and then let the user access the software. An example of a 'data system' is how Minecraft is installed and used. How can I simulate this in C#?

I have already thought about using class libraries, but I would also like to store forms and such in the external files.

Comment: How does your data system differ from a directory?

Comment: Well... I need to know some way of storing my functions/forms/classes that will be called in my program in an external source that can be updated even when the EXE is open. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daaksin You should deploy your application using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx).